# Strip characters from header in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this from an HTTP X-Forwarded-For Header:

```
15.207.26.45[CHR(0)]'"`, 10.3.94.196, 178.210.90.90, 172.31.49.107
```

I am parsing IP addresses, and would like to remove characters that have no place in a comma-delimited list of ipv4 or ipv6 IP addresses.

I tried various regexes with `gsub`, without success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that the literal character "[" followed by "C", "H", "R" etc? Also what regexp have you tried?

Comment: Are you trying to fix a broken header value? You should rather find the cause of that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Stefan. However, I get thousands of HTTP requests and the headers are all fine. This one however, caused an exception in production and was flagged by Rollbar. So I'd rather just fix the small % of malformed headers through a regexp for now. I have set it up though to warn me if this happens too often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example string of ipv4 addresses, the following should only return the ipv4 addresses and skip everything else.

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

...oh, and this will match both ipv4 and ipv6:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-f]{1,4}\:){7}[0-9a-f]{1,4}
```